# Word and Custom Content Types

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have defined a new content type (document) for sharepoint.  The problem I have is that word automatically comes up with window allowing updating of these properties (for example effective date) that is not validated and I don't want it to show when the user is uploading changes (I fill in some of these fields on the updated method in the eventreceiver class).  Is it possible to disable this or at least customize the word behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own Document Information Panels: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684925.aspx.

Another alternative might be to set the ShowInNewForm/ShowInEditForm properties of the SPField. But im not sure if Word uses them.